# Viewing changes in VS2010 / TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I retrieved a specific version of my codebase from TFS in VS2010 (not the latest version), and have made changes to that. Is it possible to do a 'view pending changes' that will compare it to the latest version? Currently 'view pending changes' is only showing me changes between mine and the version that I retrieved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Source Control Explorer, Right click on the folder that contains your changes and select "compare". This will bring up a form that has 2 paths selected, the top path should be the latest version in source control and the bottom one should be the "workspace" or "local" verison. Hit OK and you'll see a list of all the files that differ between the latest and the version you have locally. You can then double click on individual files to see the diffs.